# Are builtins like str() and int() functions or classes?

Tags: python, function, class

In Python, when we call `str(<something>)`, are we calling the function, or are we calling the class constructor (the class being `str`)? Similarly, `int()`, `complex()` etc.

Comment: Technically both.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, it invokes the `__str__` magic method for the particular object you are casting

Comment: I prefer not to know since something might change in the future. It doesn't really matter since the syntax is the same.

Comment: Case in point: `open()` is currently an ordinary function, returning a file object.  But back in the Python 2.x days, it was an alias for `file`, the actual type of file objects.  (This had to change when file objects split into two different types, to handle binary vs. text modes.)